# How to hide head and column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to hide head and column using jQuery. The below code doesn't work.

```
$('#MD116139889_ZIPCODE_InputField').find('.input-group-addon').click(function(){
    $('.116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupHead').hide();
    $('.116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupCol').hide();
});
```

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqhoL.png)

```
<div id="MD116139889_ZIPCODE_dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 76px; max-height: none;">
<div id="popUpContentResult" class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="30%" height="19" class="text-center 116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupHead">ZipId</th>
<th class="text-center 116141670_ZIPCODEPopupHead">Zip Code</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" class="text-center 116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupCol"><a href="Javascript:selectitem0();">00196</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: So first, make sure those elements exist on the page.  You can `console.log($('aselector').length);` in that click handler to see in the console if they find anything.  Without providing the markup for us to see, you're left with debugging suggestions.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: @Taplar it show 1 what does it mean?

Comment: That means it found the element, and the hide() will put the css style display:none property on it.

Comment: I try display:none but it not work. @Taplar

Answer (score 0):

I took off the find() of the bind for a simple test case, but it seems to work fine.

```js
$('#MD116139889_ZIPCODE_InputField').click(function() {
  $('.116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupHead').hide();
  $('.116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupCol').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MD116139889_ZIPCODE_dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 76px; max-height: none;">
  <div id="popUpContentResult" class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="30%" height="19" class="text-center 116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupHead">ZipId</th>
          <th class="text-center 116141670_ZIPCODEPopupHead">Zip Code</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" class="text-center 116141670_ZIPCODE_IDPopupCol"><a href="Javascript:selectitem0();">00196</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="MD116139889_ZIPCODE_InputField">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I try remove find() but two class not hide. I debug it and code is run but not hide.

Comment: I'm not saying you won't need the find() to target the elements that you are clicking that should cause the logic to happen.  I'm simply demonstrating that running the method to target those two classes and hiding them will result in the column being hidden.  At least for me in Firefox.

Comment: i know you not say. i try to do this and two code it same to working. My workspac has not button it is popup.